# Can you polymorph a python unittest test case?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I need to test the combination of two parameters, each having only a few possibilities. So I want to have a class hierarchy, where each subclass has its own fixed parameter A, while Parameter B can be tested based on that common A. I want to polymorph the test methods in the test case in terms of a shifting Parameter A, so that I don't have to rewrite the test methods for each subclass I test, but still can have variations in the subclasses' tests.

However, I found that if I declare the attribute in setUp(self). the attribute `self.A` does not get subclassed. Meaning that all my subclasses all have the same self.A value from the first test case (parent class). Also all my `testSomething(self)` methods are not virtual! Meaning with the following hierarchy:

```
class baseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print('base setup')
        self.A = 100

    def testSomething(self):
        print('base test')
        # Do something with self.A

class subTest(baseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        print('sub setup')
        self.A = 999

    def testSomething(self):
        print('sub test')
        # Do something with self.A
```

**EDIT:** I put both classes in one file, and relied on unittest.main() launched in `if __name__ == "__main__"`

Running this file gives me:

```
base setup
base test
base setup
base test
```

I thought all python methods are virtual, but this does not seem the case in unittest.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I implemented the plan below and it works as expected.
See below:

```
class baseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print('base setup')
        self.A = 100

    def testSomething(self):
        print('base test')
        self._DoTestSomething(self)

    def _DoTestSomething(self)
        # Do something with self.A

class subTest(baseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        print('sub setup')
        self.A = 999

    def _DoTestSomething(self)
        # Do something with self.A
```

**OLD**

Ok, I have a plan now.
I can write the test implementations in non testSomething() methods, which should be virtual, then delegate the testSomething() to these virtual methods.

I haven't tested this idea, but I think it should work.

Comment: why the down vote? I just implemented it and it works!

Comment: I voted this down because it's not an answer to your question. It's you saying you have a plan to try something else.

Comment: Alright, I have an update with details. Can you consider voting it back up? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're running into, but it works fine for me...?

Using your code, and then adding this:

```
a = baseTest()
b = subTest()

a.setUp()
a.testSomething()
b.setUp()
b.testSomething()
```

Here's my output:

```
base setup
base test
sub setup
sub test
```

Comment: I put both classes in one file, and relied on unittest.main()

Comment: I confirm that using Python 3.4.3, the original code, surrounded by `import unittest` and `unittest.main()`, works just fine. The output is as shown in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`testscenarios` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testscenarios/) is designed to take the test methods you write, and some data scenarios, to produce individual test cases for each combination of (test-method × scenario).

For instance:

```python
import unittest
import testscenarios

from .. import system_under_test

class foo_TestCase(testscenarios.WithScenarios, unittest.TestCase):
    """ Test cases for `foo` function. """

    scenarios = [
            ('purple': {
                'wibble': "purple",
                'expected_count': 2,
                'expected_output': "Purple",
                }),
            ('orange': {
                'wibble': "orange",
                'expected_count': 3,
                'expected_output': "Orange",
                }),
            ('red': {
                'wibble': "red",
                'expected_count': 1,
                'expected_output': "Red",
                }),
            ]

    def test_has_expected_vowel_count(self):
        """ Should give the expected count of vowels. """
        vowel_count = system_under_test.foo(self.wibble)
        self.assertEqual(self.expected_count, vowel_count)

    def test_sets_expected_output(self):
        """ Should set the output to the expected value. """
        system_under_test.foo(self.wibble)
        self.assertEqual(self.expected_output, system_under_test.output)
```

The `foo_TestCase` class will, when test discovery occurs, generate 6 tests for the test runner. They will have names annotated with the scenario names, so the resulting test report distinguishes each specific test case:

```
foo_TestCase.test_has_expected_vowel_count (purple)
foo_TestCase.test_has_expected_vowel_count (orange)
foo_TestCase.test_has_expected_vowel_count (red)
foo_TestCase.test_sets_expected_output (purple)
foo_TestCase.test_sets_expected_output (orange)
foo_TestCase.test_sets_expected_output (red)
```

More flexibility is available if you need it – see the `testscenarios` documentation – but the above demonstrates how I use it most of the time.